# Updating value of 2 textboxes with one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[name="percentdiscount"]').on('change', function() {
    applyDiscount();
  });

  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    let sum = 0;        
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sum').val(sum.toFixed(2)).data('total', sum);
    applyDiscount();
  });

  function applyDiscount() {
    var pc = parseFloat($('input[name="percentdiscount"]:checked').val());
    $('#sum').val(function() {
      return ($(this).data('total') * pc).toFixed(2);
    });
    $('#totalcost').val(function() {
      return ($(this).data('total') * pc).toFixed(2);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="agencydiscount">
  <h1>6. Agency Discount</h1>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" value="1" checked>
    None
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="10percent" value="0.9">
    10% Discount
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="15percent" value="0.85">
    15% Discount
  </label>
</div>

<div class="runningtotal">
  Running CPC Total (in £): <input id="sum" type="text" readonly="true" value="0.00" data-total="0" />
  Total Cost (in £): <input id="totalcost" type="text" readonly="true" value="0 (until clicks specified)" data-total="0" />
</div>
```

When this function runs I am trying to have it multiply 2 separate textbox values (`#sum` and `#totalcost`) by the `percentdiscount` value, but whenever the function runs the `#totalcost` textbox value is just going to 0.

What am I doing wrong?

`percentdiscount` value is 0.9 or 0.85, depending on which of the two radio buttons is clicked.

Also, please assume the `#sum` is a value other than 0.00, for example assume it to be 0.40.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant HTML to the question so we can create a working example of the problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan of course

Comment: [`.val(..)`](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) doesn't accept a function as the argument. It expects the first argument to be String or Number or Array.

Comment: @Titus `.val(..) doesn't accept a function as the argument` yes it does. Your own link to the docs shows this. It accepts a function which returns the new value to set. The usage in the OP is correct.

Comment: where your checkboxes !! input[type=checkbox] ???

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Oh, yes, that is right. I haven't read the documentation, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[name="percentdiscount"]').on('change', function() {
    var data = $(this).val();
    $(".test").val(data)
    
    
  });

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="agencydiscount">
  <h1>6. Agency Discount</h1>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" value="1" checked>
    None
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="10percent" value="0.9">
    10% Discount
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="15percent" value="0.85">
    15% Discount
  </label>
</div>

<div class="runningtotal">
  Running CPC Total (in £): <input id="sum" type="text" readonly="true" value="0.00" data-total="0" class="test"/>
  Total Cost (in £): <input id="totalcost" type="text" readonly="true" value="0 (until clicks specified)" data-total="0"  class="test"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just write code for them.

Comment: I'm not sure what this javascript is doing; it should be multiplying the value in 'sum' by the value of 'percent discount', and then multiplying the value in 'totalcost' by the same value of 'percent discount'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$("input:not(#totalcost)").click(function() {
  let valu, num,
      multiplier = Number($(this).attr("value")),
      sum = Number($("#sum").val());
      name = $(this).attr("name");
      
  num = multiplier * sum;
  valu = Math.round((num + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100;
  $("#totalcost").val(valu);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="agencydiscount">
  <h1>6. Agency Discount</h1>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="percentdiscount" value="0" checked>
    None
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="10percent" value="0.9">
    10% Discount
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="percentdiscount" id="15percent" value="0.85">
    15% Discount
  </label>
</div>

<div class="runningtotal">
  Running CPC Total (in £): <input id="sum" type="text" readonly="true" value="0.40" data-total="0" />
  Total Cost (in £): <input id="totalcost" type="text" readonly="true" value="0 (until clicks specified)" data-total="0" />
</div>
```

If you need to change the value if "None" is checked, just change its value in html or write an if statement.